# Is it possilble to set value to minimum after maximum is reached in input type number

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I need to go back to 0 on click after 23 is reached in the `input type= number` in angular.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Hour</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="23" class="form-control" formControlName="hour">
</div>
```

Here I have set minimum value of input to zero and maximum to 23. When 23 is reached again on clicking i need to show 0 instead of stuck on 23.

Comment: I get the feeling this is to indicate hours, why not use a different input type? Also, your label isn't linked to you input :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to do the exact thing you want, you need to detect the value of the input field which is why I added the ***hourChanged*** function. You also need to increase the max number for your input field to 24 instead of 23 so that you can still increase after 23 and change it to 0 because if you don't change the max number, when the value is 23, it will not show 23 and instead, will be changed to 0.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <label for="hour" class="form-label">Hour</label>
   <input type="number" min="0" max="24" class="form-control" formControlName="hour" (input)="hourChanged($event.target.value)">
</div>
```

Add this function in your page.component.ts

```
hourChanged(e: string) {
 if (Number(e) && Number(e) > 23) {
   this.formName.get('hour').setValue(0);
 }
}
```

Comment: but i am getting an error that propet value doesnt exists @dom.macs

Comment: I'm glad I could help!